# Access variables in Python console for debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, spyder

The main Python code calls my written functions that for better overview are stored in separate .py files. For improvement of my code the program shall start from the beginning and stop at a defined position where I want to do some repair. After stopping I want to have access to the local variables where the code has stopped. *This means I want to select some code that was performed before the halt and manipulate this code in the console.* After testing in the console I want to correct my original code and run again the program.

> *Example:*

You suppose that the following line doesn't execute as you expect:

```
if a.find('xyz')==-1:
```

Therefore you stop the program just before:

```
breakpoint()
if a.find('xyz')==-1:
```

Now you want to find out why exactly the line is not working as you  expected. Maybe it depends on the variable `a` or on the string `xyz` or the `find` command is not correctly applied? So I would now enter `a.find('xyz')` in the console, vary and adjust the command. After a few tests in the console I find out that the right command must be `a.find('XYZ')`. Now I correct the line in my original code and restart the program. ---
But this is not possible because the halt command `breakpoint()` or `pdb.set_trace()` prohibits me from using the console. Instead I end up in debug mode where I can only run through the code line by line or display variables.

How can I debug my code as desired?

The following workarounds also do not help:

1. `sys.exit()`

   I stop the code with `sys.exit()`. Main problem with this method is that I have no access to the variables if the code has stopped in another file. Also I do not see where the program has stopped. If I have several `sys.exit()` instances distributed in large code I do not know at which instance it has stopped. I can define individual outputs by `sys.exit(‘position1’)`, `sys.exit(‘position2’)`, but still I have to manually find the file and scroll to the given position.
2. cells

   I define cells with `#%%`. Then I can run these  cells separately, but I cannot run all cells from the beginning until the end of a given cell.

Spyder 5.2.2

Comment: are you trying to access local variables within a function or variables that have global scope within a module?

Comment: the problem appears in both cases

Comment: When you use `pdb.set_trace()`, you get the `ipdb>` prompt in the IPython console, and you are not restricted to displaying variables - you can enter `a.find('XYZ')` or any other expression as you would normally in the console. Adding a breakpoint in Spyder does the same. (Unless there's something radically different in Spyder v5 - this all works for me in 4.1.5)

Comment: This worked and it is even mentioned in the documentation "This allows breakpoints and the execution flow to be viewed and controlled right from the Spyder GUI, as well as with all the familiar IPython console commands." https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/debugging.html; but later only breakpoints and code flow are demonstrated in detail but not console operations.

Comment: The [`pdb` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb)  may be more helpful, and note that most of the functions are not dependent on Spyder or Ipython but will work in any console.